# How should I build a Fetch (Post) data array/structure from scratch? How do I join two arrays? Is it necessary for Fetch?

Tags: arrays, fetch, key-pair

I need to build some kind of data structure/array starting with nothing and from a loop where the data is available. These would be key/value pairs. I tried initializing an empty cartData array [] in my javascript file, then using push, but this does not appear to be the right thing. This is a shopping cart program. I have all of the customer data captured in an array that looks like {First Name: firstName, Last Name: lastName, Email: emailAddress,... ,} and from the console it appears to have worked and in that form. For cartData, I'm getting something like

{Book_Title1: Price1},{Book_Title2: Price2},...{},{}

as a collection of objects. When I added to the cartData = [] array I gathered the data inside the loop and used the following method

cartData.push({[purchaseItem]: purchasePrice})

to add new items to the empty array. What I get is a collection of objects that look like

{BookTitle1: Price1}, {BookTitle2: Price2},...{}, {}

are the {}brackets unnecessary? There seem to be a number of opinions without examples. I was assuming that the first structure shown here is what is needed for Fetch to post the way a  normally presents data. I could be wrong on that also. I need to know the correct way to do it and a way to combine the two data sets (three if we count the Key/Value pair for grand $total.) My goal is to have the customer hit the purchase button, the cart/form data to go to Formspree.io and for them to send an email with all of this order information. It works well enough with an unadulterated . I just need to amend the data for the cart.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be short and clear. Also use [Syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) when you write code.

Comment: My apologies. I've gone beyond this question and have learned to use PHP cURL which is much more appropriate for my purposes. I've forced myself to learn these things and hopefully my questions in the future will be better informed.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide a snippet of the code that you've written, because it's not really clear what format are you sending the data in.

Your question seems to imply that you're sending the request body as an array. That is incorrect. It has to be a JSON.

Secondly make sure you add the 'Content-Type: application/json' header to your request